# How to keep comparing pairs of integers until user inputs 0 without array?

Tags: c, input, multiple-conditions

This is a program to check for co-prime pairs.

I'm trying to write a program to receive input of integers until user inputs 0, this was easy enough to solve with the help of an array(I already did it with an array) because there's only one value at a time to be read and checked. 
With an array it's simply:

`for(i = 0; i < n-1; i++)`

then compare `v[i]` and `v[i+1]`

I'm trying to apply this exact checking algorithm without an array, though,
reading two values and comparing them, somehow, the loop only ends when I input 0 more than once, sometimes two times, sometimes three.

```
#include <stdio.h>


int gcd1(int a, int b) //function containing Euclid's algorithm 
{
    while (b != 0)
    {
        int temp = a%b;

        a = b;
        b = temp;
    }


    return a;   
}


int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{

    int num1, num2; /* both of these vars would otherwise have a non-zero 
    value if I was using Try Nr.1 written in bold below was applied */

    int cate = 0, flag = 1;
    while(1)
    {
        scanf("%d %d", &num1, &num2);

        if(num1 == 0 && num2 == 0)
        {
        break;
        }

        if(gcd1(num1, num2) == 1) //check if pair is co-prime 
        {
            cate++;
        }

    }
        printf("%d\n", cate);


    return 0;
}
```

Things I've tried:

**1 -**

```
while(num1 != 0 || num2 != 0) /*using this inside the while(), also tried
changing the operator to &&, without a condition and a break inside the 
body*/
```

**2 -**

Tried a `while(flag != 0)` that changes `if(num1 == 0 || num2 == 0)`, changed the operator to `&&` too but it's still the same, or didn't make sense to me.

What I need from the program is to stop at any input 0, for example:

```
25 27 12 24 11 13 0
```

the program should stop there and tell me how many pairs are co-prime but it only stops when I input 0 two more times.

Comment: Begin with checking what [`scanf` *returns*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf#Return_value).

Comment: `if (num1 == 0 || num2 == 0) break;` <- maybe that is, what you want?

Comment: *this was easy enough to solve with the help of an array* Where's the array? Did you mean this was easy to solve without the help of arrays? If so, it's absolutely correct.

Comment: Inasmuch as you describe an I/O problem, using an array *vs.* two separate scalar variables as the I/O destination has nothing whatever to do with it.

Comment: I meant that i solved this same problem but with an array, and it was not nearly as hard as this.

Comment: Do yourself a favour: Indent your code consistently. The simple reason is that this follows the structure of your program and it makes it easier to read. Preferably, use an automated tool (autoindenter, many IDEs have a builtin one) for that to get consistent results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that after you test 15 vs 63 you throw them *both* away, so 63 doesn't get a chance to be tested vs 43. Instead of always reading *two* numbers, read just *one*, and throw away also just *one*, along the lines of

```
    read a
    while ()
        read b
        gcd(a, b), etc
        a = b
```

Comment: But this way it will test for first input against all the other inputs instead of arr[i], arr[i+1] if I was using arrays. And that’s what I wanted. Every number with its neighbor.

Comment: @RamiRaghfan No. Pay attention to the `a = b` assignment. Now the second input plays the role of the first, etc.

Answer (score 5):

> What I need from the program is to stop at any input 0

`scanf("%d %d", &num1, &num2);` is blocking until you enter 2 numbers

if you want to stop when the first number is 0 without having to read the second number you have to do 2 *scanf*

```
scanf("%d", &num1);

if(num1 == 0)
  break;

scanf("%d", &num2);

if(num2 == 0)
  break;
```

Comment: this worked to some extent, but is apparently unreliable as it didn't work with the test input provided by the problem.

Comment: @RamiRaghfan 15 63 are not co primer, nor 43 and 129, nor  55 and 15 , why do you expect 3 ?

Comment: because gcd(15, 63)=1, gcd(129, 55)=1, and gcd(15, 4)=1. this algorithm is supposed to compare each number with the number next to it.

Comment: @RamiRaghfan gcd(15,63) is 3 !

Comment: sorry i meant gcd(63, 43) which is equal to 1 instead of writing gcd(15, 63) in my above comment.